# How to update a Text widget automatically - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a simple timer to know how much time has passed from a date to a current date

but the problem I have is that the Text widget is only painted once but it does not update, and I would like the text to update every 1 second. And not have to refresh the page, is it possible to do that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerPageState createState() => _TimerPageState();
}

class _TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final start = DateTime(2020, 8, 10, 16, 30, 0);
    final currentdate= DateTime.now();
    final comparation = currentdate.difference(start);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Start time: " + start.toString()),
              Divider(),
              Text(
                "time elapsed = " + comparation.toString().substring(0, 7),
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5abd8c), fontSize: 26),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

I try this:

```
Timer timer;
  final start = DateTime(2020, 8, 17, 21, 30, 0);
  final dateActual = DateTime.now();
  Duration comparation = new Duration(hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0);
  @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      setState(() {
        comparation = dateActual.difference(start);
        print(comparation);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Start time: " + start.toString()),
              Divider(),
              Text(
                "time elapsed = " + comparation.toString().substring(0, 7),
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5abd8c), fontSize: 26),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Hi! Yes I tried but it didn't work for me

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I update the question, this is what a tried

Comment: You changed your original code. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: Move `final dateActual = DateTime.now();` to right above the `setState` in the timer.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore It worked! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you want a `Timer` from the `dart:async` library, specifically a [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).

Instantiate one in `initState` of your `StatefulWidget` and cancel it in `dispose`.

`Timer.periodic` takes a callback that fires after every duration that's passed. Since your `DateTime` difference calculation is already done in `build`, you just need to trigger a rebuild with `setState`.

```dart
Timer timer;

@override
void initState() {
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
    setState(() {});
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
}
```

It's not possible to do this without rebuilding, at the very least, the `Text` widget that's being changed. I don't think it's necessary since there isn't much in this `build` method, but if you wanted to do that, you would have to extract all of the necessary time calculations, timer, and single `Text` widget to its own `StatefulWidget`, so that only the one widget that's necessary to be rebuilt, is rebuilt.

Ideally, you should also be doing the time calculations outside of the `build` method, but it's not a huge deal in this case and you'll get something that works.

Comment: I had to change the first line to `Timer? timer;`, otherwise, it was giving me not initialized error.

Comment: @TrigonaMinima This answer was made before null-safety in Dart was a thing. Doing `late final Timer timerl` would be even better.